# Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path _id for model with getAll during populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a list of permissions for a role,

here's what I am trying to do in my permissions,

```
const PermissionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

PermissionsSchema.statics = {
  get(id) {
    return this.findById(id)
      .exec()
      .then((permission) => {
        if (permission) {
          return permission;
        }
        const err = new APIError('No such permission exists!', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  },

  list({ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}) {
    return this.find()
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip(+skip)
      .limit(+limit)
      .exec();
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Permission', PermissionsSchema);
```

and this in my roles model.

```
const RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  permissions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Permission'
  }],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

RoleSchema.statics = {
  get(id) {
    // const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.fromString(id);
    return this.findById(id)
      // .populate('permissions')
      .exec()
      .then((role) => {
        if (role) {
          return role;
        }
        const err = new APIError('No such role exists!', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  },

  list({ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}) {
    return this.find()
      .populate('permissions')
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip(+skip)
      .limit(+limit)
      .exec();
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema);
```

and when I try to get all, I get this error

`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ADD_USER" at path "_id" for model "Permission"`

I've gone through some other posts but they all say I need to pass _id as a string, but I am not querying myself, how would I cast _id?

Answer (score 0):

So I already had some documents in my collection which didn't have any kind of ID in them.